# How can I create a 9-patch that can preserve circle of this image?

Tags: android, image, nine-patch

I have this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Iab.png
[image]

I want to preserve the circle at the bottom of the image so I make this 9-patch
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNWdE.png
[image]

but somehow in the mobile the circle becomes ellipse like this
[image]

i don't know why the bottom part get stretch.
Any help please, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the 9 patch you created is wrong.
And unoptimized (you can make it much smaller): the upper black line should leave a transparent hole corresponding to the circle.
The black lines result in a stretched area, while the parts you leave out aren't stretched.
So, just leave the area you don't want to stretch transparent.
This is the reference [site](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)